# Anytime algorithm in Node.js

Tags: node.js, performance, algorithm

"An [anytime algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anytime_algorithm) is an algorithm that can return a valid solution to a problem even if it's interrupted at any time before it ends. The algorithm is expected to find better and better solutions the more time it keeps running".

My question is: how can I write an anytime algorithm in Node.js?

I have a function that looks like the following (pseudo-code):

```
function findBestSolution(input) {
  var bestSolutionSoFar = EMPTY_SOLUTION;  // initialization
  for (var i=1; i<=1000000; ++i) {
    var newSolution = findNewSolution(...);   // this might take a long time
    if (newSolution.quality() > bestSolutionSoFar.quality())
       bestSolutionSoFar = newSolution;
  }
  return bestSolutionSoFar;
}
```

Now, this function takes a long time to run because of the long loop and the lengthy calculation of new solutions.

What I want is to enable the calling function to interrupt this function at any time, and get the current "bestSolutionSoFar".

So, for example, the user may start to run the function, then go and drink some coffee, then come back and interrupt the function and it will give him the best solution it has found so far.

Comment: I don't understand why this has anything to do with NodeJS. It sounds like any monotonic converging algorithm and Node specific tools are irrelevant...

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum As you can see in the answer, there are implementation details that are specific to Node.js

Comment: The answer is completely irrelevant to the problem and the person who has written it probably did not run into the concept of "anytime algorithm" in AI literature before. The concept of "anytime algorithm" just means it is expected to perform in the case there is an environmental need change. It is characterized by the everlasting balance between exploration and exploitation in AI. The point where you have to stop performing deliberation and react in a more reactive way. It characterizes a desirable property of an algorithm. It has nothing to do with Node itself. Also, anything monotone works.

Comment: If this is unclear - "Using Anytime Algorithms in Intelligent Systems" covers it.

Comment: Maybe in AI the concept has a different meaning. But according to the Wikipedia page I linked to, the concept "anytime algorithm" is related to the user interrupting the execution of the algorithm before it is complete.

Comment: If this is unclear - "Using Anytime Algorithms in Intelligent Systems" covers it. IIRC (read it during MultiAgent course so that was some time ago) - they describe monotonicity and performance profiles, that should definitely get you started. If your question is just: " How do I get an intermediate result of a calculation in JavaScript" then it's an interesting question on its own but the term anytime algorithm is used incorrectly here.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - You should probably re-read the work you cite as you do not appear to recall correctly despite your remarkable certainty. N.B. the section on page 77 - "Interruptible and Contract Algorithms." To clarify, since you did not provide a link, I retrieved [a paper by that name](http://rbr.cs.umass.edu/papers/Zaimag96.html) as Bing's first result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any specific requirements (or ideas about) how you want the interrupt to take place? One general approach would be something like the following (which does nothing more than increment a counter as its work step, but hopefully conveys the general idea).

```
function Solver(){
    this.intermediateAnswer = 0;
    this.wrapItUp = false;
    this.finalCallback = undefined;
};

Solver.prototype.interrupt = function(){
    this.wrapItUp = true;
};

Solver.prototype.solve = function(startWith, cb) {
    var self = this;
    function workStep(){
        if (self.wrapItUp)
            return self.finalCallback(self.intermediateAnswer);
        self.intermediateAnswer = self.intermediateAnswer + 1;
        setImmediate(workStep);
    };

    this.finalCallback = cb;
    this.intermediateAnswer = startWith;
    setImmediate(workStep);
};

var solver = new Solver();
solver.solve(1,function(result){
    console.log('got to: ' + result);
});

// tell it to stop after five seconds

setTimeout(function(){solver.interrupt();}, 5000);
```

The result:

```
got to: 1790178
```

...or thereabouts - as would be expected the final value bounces around a little bit around 1.8mil.

There are other ways you could package this (for example using promises or possibly ES6 generators rather than the callback) as well as using other things to trigger the interrupt. I will be curious to see other answers myself, primarily for intellectual curiousity. Please comment if this is in the direction you are thinking or what its deficiencies may be in the context of your planned use.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a good solution. The problem is that my "solve" function is complex and it is difficult to convert it to an asynchronous function. But that is for another question.

Comment: You're welcome. I see you've had some responses to your other question about converting a function to async. Hopefully the conversion won't be too tedious and good luck with it.